# Using select query for IN Clause, along with hardcoded values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have some code where I am selecting rows that have any of the following hardcoded `SETID` values. This is part of additional code being rolled into a SQL View.

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_TABLE1 B
WHERE B.SETID IN ('11000', '18000', '41000', '41001')
```

In addition to the above hardcoded values, I would like to add in another much longer list of `SETID`'s between the range `'90000' and '90999'` that are contained in a table `PS_LOC_GL`. I would prefer to use the `BETWEEN` operator, so that I don't have to list out each value in this range. I haven't been able to find a method to select both the hardcoded values, and use a `BETWEEN` operator together.

This is what I have come up with so far, however I don't believe I can use variables inside SQL views, so while this works as native SQL code, it will not work inside my view:

```
DECLARE @SET_ID_LIST table (SETID varchar(5))
INSERT @SET_ID_LIST(SETID) VALUES ('11000'), ('18000'), ('41000'), ('41001');

SELECT *
FROM TEST_TABLE1 B
WHERE B.SETID IN (
    SELECT SETID FROM @SET_ID_LIST 
    UNION
    SELECT SETID FROM PS_LOC_GL
)
```

Are there any other options I have where I can use both the hardcoded list of values, along with more of a dynamic list based on the `PS_LOC_GL` table that only has `SETID` values in the `'90000'` to `'90999'` range.

Comment: Why doesn't your last query work?

Comment: I thought you couldn't use variables inside SQL Views? Is that not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a `OR` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_TABLE1 B
WHERE B.SETID IN (SELECT SETID FROM PS_LOC_GL /* WHERE SETID BETWEEN ... */)
OR    B.SETID IN ('11000', '18000', '41000', '41001')
```

If you want to use `UNION` then use the `(VALUES ...)` clause to append the hardcoded list of values:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_TABLE1 B
WHERE B.SETID IN (
    SELECT SETID FROM PS_LOC_GL /* WHERE SETID BETWEEN ... */
    UNION
    SELECT SETID FROM (VALUES
        ('11000'),
        ('18000'),
        ('41000'),
        ('41001')
    ) AS v(SETID)
)
```

Comment: I can't use variables in a SQL view

Comment: @nick sorry it was a typo.

Comment: I think your last solution will work the best for me!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just `OR` the other condition? `IN` actually is a shortcut for multiple `OR`s, so just append to it.

```
SELECT *
       FROM test_table1 b
       WHERE b.setid IN ('11000', '18000', '41000', '41001')
              OR b.setid IN (SELECT setid
                                    FROM ps_loc_gl);
```

Or with a `BETWEEN` operation something like:

```
SELECT *
       FROM test_table1 b
       WHERE b.setid IN ('11000', '18000', '41000', '41001')
              OR b.setid BETWEEN (SELECT min(setid)
                                  FROM ps_loc_gl)
                                 AND (SELECT max(setid)
                                             FROM ps_loc_gl);
```

Comment: For some reason the OR really makes the overall query run slower. There is a lot of aggregation occuring within the main query.